# Teensy and MS5803 sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, i2c, library, teensy

I'm trying to use the [MS5803 pressure sensor](http://www.meas-spec.com/product/t_product.aspx?id=8684) with a Teensy 3.2. Compiling the [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12909), or other, libraries, however, results in no output.

Can you provide guidance on how to modify the libraries to work with the Teensy (t3_i2c)?

Comment: Why not ask on the Teensy forum? In any case links to the sensor, the libraries, and providing your code would make your question more meaningful.